# Using a shared file variable in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, netsh

I am trying to execute a remote command to perform netsh command. The command will do a export of the nps configuration file and output it to a shared path. But, the command always give me an error `"Access is denied"`. I realised the problem lies in the shared path value (`\\shared-pc\temp`). Without it, I am able to execute it successfully eg (`C:\Users\User1\Desktop`). I am able to browse to the shared location from the local and remote PC. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Below is the command. Thanks.

```
invoke-command -computername nap1 -scriptblock {netsh nps export filename = "\\shared-pc\temp\config.xml" exportPSK = yes}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the double-hop / second-hop authentication problem. You're credentials is passed to the `nap1`-server, but `nap1` doesn't have the permission to pass on the same credentials(yours) to the fileserver to get access.

The solution to is to use [CredSSP](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-quot-second-hop-quot-functionality-with-credssp.aspx)

There are some mixed feelings about how smart it is to use in a production enviroment, but that's up to your company to decide.